# A collection declared in separate file not loaded before Meteor.startup runs server side in Meteor application

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, meteor

I have just started using Meteor on Mac. I made a simple app with two .coffee files in the server directory: bootstrap.coffee and publish.coffee.

The content of the bootstrap.coffee starts like this:

```
Meteor.startup ->
  if RaceDays.find().count() is 0
```

and so on.

The content of the publish.coffee is:

```
RaceDays = new Meteor.Collection("racedays")

Meteor.publish "racedays", ->
  RaceDays.find()
```

The problem is when I run the application with the meteor command I get the following error:

```
20130917-15:42:00.967(1)? (STDERR /Users/gnidde/Projects/test/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:184
W20130917-15:42:00.970(1)? (STDERR) }).run();
W20130917-15:42:00.971(1)? (STDERR)    ^
W20130917-15:42:00.979(1)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: RaceDays is not defined
W20130917-15:42:00.980(1)? (STDERR)     at server/q.coffee:3:5
W20130917-15:42:00.981(1)? (STDERR)     at mains (/Users/gnidde/Projects/test/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:157:61)
W20130917-15:42:00.981(1)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20130917-15:42:00.982(1)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/gnidde/.meteor/tools/3cba50c44a/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20130917-15:42:00.984(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/gnidde/Projects/test/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:157:5
```

It seems that the Meteor.startup is run before the publish.coffee file is loaded but that should not be the case if I understood the documentation correctly.
I also tried to change it to use .js files instead but there was no difference.

If I remove the publish.coffee file and place the code at the top of the bootstrap.coffee file it works.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare coffeescript variables as global with `@`:

```
@RaceDays = new Meteor.Collection("racedays");
```

This is due to how Meteor variable shadowing works in connection with coffeescript automatic variable declaration.

In plain Javascript in Meteor, variables declared with `var` are bound to the file they're declared:

```
var LocalRaceDays = ...; // this is visible only in the file it's defined

RaceDays = ...; // this is visible everywhere
```

Obviously, all collections should be defined in the second way.

However, coffeescript by default does the "smart" variable declaration by itself - basically by placing `var variableName` in the first place in javascript where the variable is visible. In your case, this causes `RaceDays` to be declared by `var` in js, and therefore they're scoped to the file.

Using `@` char supersedes this default behavior by binding the variable to `this`, `global` or `window` object instead.